# Sorting Installed BREW Packages by Install Size

Tags: github, command-line-interface, homebrew

I know I can `brew ls` to get a summary of everything I have installed using Homebrew. I was recently cleaning up some unused packages and was a bit surprised that mysql was taking up 1.7Gb.

Is there some way I can sort the list, or at least get more information, for install size on all of my packages directly in the Terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do `which brew`, get to that dir eg (`/usr/local/Cellar`) then do

`brew install coreutils`

`du -hs * | gsort -h` it will show sizes of directories